# How can you make the bounding box of text in an HTML5 canvas account for transformations such as panning and scaling?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm, canvas

I've been playing with a Javascript program which is composed of an HTML5 Canvas that can be panned and zoomed. Text can also be added and a bounding box is initially generated for it. I've got the program to account for the panning transformations, but I'm unable to get the bounding box to account for the scaling/zooming in and out. The initial bounding box is also not perfect, although it works when you try to click and drag the text, it is off by quite a bit.

Please help me figure out how to fix these issues.

Here is the program: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyAcorn77/hekagmb2/2/

```
/* I use this code to account for panning transformations for the bounding box on line   
   362 

   The Zooming/Scaling function can be found on line 372 which is what I am unable to 
   adjust the bounding box for.

*/
```

- Click and hold to drag the text
- Left click to default to inital display transformation values

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the matrices
Try adjusting the matrices
Try adjusting the matrices
Try adjusting the matrices
Try adjusting the matrices